# extjs grid sort error - still works but errors in console window

Tags: extjs, grid

I have an ExtJs grid, when I click sort, it does in fact sort the grid, but in the console window I get error messages.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSynchronized' of undefined
at constructor.addCls (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:34688)
at constructor.addCls (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:63226)
at constructor.disable (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:63902)
at constructor.callParent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:11709)
at constructor.disable (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:123642)
at constructor.ddDisable (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:175799)
at constructor.handleMouseDown (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:134260)
at constructor.handleMouseDown (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:138266)
at constructor.callParent (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:11709)
at constructor.handleMouseDown (ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1487248312797:139491)
```

I also get the following error on startup... not sure if its related
[image]

Comment: Do you override `getTargetEl()` method somewhere? Since both errors have something to do with `cls` property, it is likely, they are related.

Comment: Please have look for this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31052434/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-issynchronized-of-undefined You are missing cls somewhere